# Magento2 hide custom shipping method based on product attribute

Tags: php, magento2, magento-2.0

I am new to Magento2.

I have created a new shipment method programmatically and name it "Same Day Delivery".
Also, I have created a product attribute programmatically and name it "Same Day Delivery Available: (Yes/No).

I would like to add the restriction on the Checkout page - If all items in cart have (Same Day Delivery Available as Yes). Then display the new shipment option or hide them in the shipment selection section.

Here is my source code:
https://github.com/balajimrv/app

Comment: You need to have your code etc. needed to answer your question here, no links to 3rd party sites please.

Answer (score 0):

In the method `Balaji\CustomShipping\Model\Carrier\Customshipping::collectRates` add after the enabled verification

```
if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
    return false;
}
```

this code that checks if same day delivery is available

```
foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
    if (!$item->getProduct()->getData('same_day_delivery_available')) { //use here the real attribute code you have on the product
        return false;
    }
}
```

you also need to tell magento to load your attribute when loading partial product data in checkout.
For this create the file `etc/catalog_attributes.xml` with this content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/catalog_attributes.xsd">    
    <group name="quote_item">
        <attribute name="same_day_delivery_available"/><!-- Use here the real attribute code -->
    </group>
    
</config>
```